# How can I prevent applications to overwrite files with no prompt?

Tags: macos-catalina, whatsapp, overwrite

When download files and there is already a file with the same name, I expect to be prompted for a decision to rename or overwrite the file. But this is not happening with WhatsApp Desktop for MacOS (10.15). This software is writing files with same name with no alert. From time to time I forget to avoid this pitfall, and sometimes with big loss of work done.

I don't kwon if it happens with other applications. I'm surprised that there is no question like this, so am I the only guy that has this kind of problem?

So, my question is: is there a way in MacOs 10.15 (or in WhatsApp Desktop) that prevents applications to overwrite files with no prior question?

Comment: Are you OK to create all downloaded file read-only?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, this is a nice approach and could work, thanks for this suggestion. This will force rename when trying overwrite. I'm going to try it.